# MySQL date fetched with one hour behind from PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hi please help me with this one. And dont downvote because I have done research, but did not find anything.

I have a weird issue where my MySQL datetime fields are in the correct DayLight saving times. But when I select them through PHP they are still in Winter time, meaning minus one hour.

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**
Timezone is GMT+1 which is correct. My MySql DB is also correct.

Comment: make sure your timezones are correct.

Comment: Check the time on the web server.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the box right to question box states clearly: `Provide details. Share your research.` The question does not fit this very basic rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about mysql.

It is about your default php timezone settings.

see

http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: thanks ! when asking a noob question people are very eager to downvote, thank YOU for answering :-)